# How can I track a form element that has no unique identifiers other than name in Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a form that is split into 5 stages. The form has the same ID for each stage.

I want to be able to track the clicks for the next buttons on each stage, but they have no unique identifiers other than the input name:

How can I identify the name in the trigger? I have tried several of the built-in variables but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The built in "Click Element" variable returns the actual DOM object that has been clicked with all its properties.

So you could do a custom javascript variable with

```
function() {
var clicked = {{Click Element}};
clickedName = clicked.getAttribute('name');
if(clickedName == null) {
return false;
} 
return clickedName;
}
```

You need to activate Click Element first. The function will return the name of the clicked element or "false" if there is no name attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. 

I was hoping to avoid any customisation and use everything 'out of the box' as it were, but your answer makes sense.